# How to go back in browser's history with physical back button?

Tags: java, blackberry, browser, navigation

I'm making an app in which I open a `BrowserField` and the user can navigate further to links present in the web page. The problem is that when I press the physical back button, the previous screen is presented while I want to present the previous page in the `BrowserField` itself. How to do that? Is that even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`BrowserFieldHistory`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserFieldHistory.html) to go back to previous pages using the `canGoBack()` and `goBack()` methods. Just over-ride the `keyChar` method to control the `ESCAPE` key input and put your own logic like so:

```
public boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) {
  if ( key == Characters.ESCAPE) {
    if(yourBrowserField.getHistory().canGoBack()){
      yourBrowserField.getHistory().goBack();
    }else{
      UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);
      return true;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know there was a BrowserFieldHistory! I'll check this and get back to you...

Comment: Weird...try returning true in all cases.

Comment: Try `yourBrowserField.getHistory().go(-1);`

Comment: My bad...I was returning `false`!

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is **Possible**.

Try this code:

```
public class NewsBrowserScreen extends MainScreen 
{
int current_index,popup;
String url;
VerticalFieldManager vertical;
BrowserField browserField;
BrowserFieldConfig browserFieldConfig;
BrowserFieldHistory browserFieldHistory;

public NewsBrowserScreen(int current_index,int popup,String url) 
{
    this.current_index=current_index;
    this.popup=popup;
    this.url=url;
    createGUI();
}
private void createGUI()    
{       
    vertical=new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR|HORIZONTAL_SCROLL|HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
    browserFieldConfig=new BrowserFieldConfig();
    browserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);     
    browserField=new BrowserField(browserFieldConfig);
    browserFieldHistory=browserField.getHistory();
    vertical.add(browserField);
    add(vertical);
    browserField.requestContent(url);
}
public boolean onClose() 
{
    if(browserFieldHistory.canGoBack())
    {
        browserFieldHistory.goBack();           
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        browserFieldHistory.clearHistory();
        return super.onClose();
    }   
}
}
```

Enough;

Comment: This is the same as @tipycalFlow's answer... :( ...except for clearHistory().

Comment: I used this class in somany applications; Is this working or not? or helped or not? Did you test this class? see the difference of both;

Comment: The other answer was right all along...I was making a stupid mistake...so I've already accepted it...although your answer is also correct so I've given you a +1 :)